# How to "navigate" to Specifically hub position Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a hub with 5 positions, and i just want to put a button and when i click,go to Specifically position... In Pivot control i can use SelectedItems with Index Position but here... I don't know

```
<Grid x:Name="MainFragment" >
            <Hub  x:Name="hubMain" Header="Você no mundo, o mundo em você!" Margin="1,0,0,0">
                <HubSection x:Name="HubOne" Header="A Faculdade dos Guararapes">
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Border CornerRadius="50" Background="White" Opacity="0.5" >
                            </Border>
                            <Image Source="/Assets/Fg.png" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Image>
                            <TextBlock Text="A Faculdade dos Guararapes tem por finalidade desenvolver processos de formação de nível superior, envolvendo o ensino, a pesquisa e a extensão, a prestação de serviços à comunidade, a investigação e a difusão da cultura, da ciência, da tecnologia e das artes." TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,125,0,0"  />
                            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" CornerRadius="50" Width="364" Height="150" Margin="11,0" >
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush  Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/apresentacao.png"/>
                                </Border.Background>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HubSection>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.ScrollToSection(HubSectionName)` is the key, my friend. If you name for both hub and hub sections then on click of the button following should work for you.

```
private void MyBtnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    hubMain.ScrollToSection(HubOne);
}
```

However, I wouldn't suggest you to navigate like that, as it would defeat the purpose of Hub template.

Comment: Thank you so MUCH!! i really need this