# How can I navigate to a specific hub when I come back from another page Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have two HubSections....

The First....

```
<HubSection  Header="Graduação Piedade - Jaboatão">
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <ListView x:Name="List"  SelectedItem="true" SelectionChanged="Lista_Gradua_Pie">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Image Source="/Assets/adm.jpg" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <Border Background="#A5000000" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                        <TextBlock Text="Administração" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="26.667" Foreground="#CCFFFFFF" Padding="15,20"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
```

and Second....

```
<HubSection  Header="Graduação Recife">
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <ListView SelectedItem="true" SelectionChanged="Lista_Recife">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Image Source="/Assets/mecan.jpg" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <Border Background="#A5000000" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                        <TextBlock Text="Engenharia Mecânica" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="26.667" Foreground="#CCFFFFFF" Padding="15,20"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
```

and as you can see inside of my "SelectionChanged" i have this..

```
var a = sender as ListView;
        if (a.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Adm)));
        }
```

But, everytime when i comeback to page (adm) he go to first HubSection, but what i want is go to the hubSection what i wish!

Comment: It's not clear, the Hub is on Adm page?

Comment: Adm is just a page, what i want is when i back from this page Adm, he go to secondHub!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30091659/how-to-navigate-to-specifically-hub-position-windows-phone-8-1

Answer (score 0):

In OnNavigatedTo() you can set the [Hub.DefaultSectionIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.hub.defaultsectionindex.aspx) property.